# Android: presenting a custom layout for text input

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, android-source, android-input-method

I have a task, the task is to modify one of the Android stock applications (Settings app) and change the behavior of text input, meaning that each time the user presses an EditText what I would like to obtain is:

- Another Activity/Fragment is started
- The new Activity/Fragment has a custom layout including an EditText
- When the user is done entering text he can press the Done button on the keyboard and go back to the previous activity, the changes to the EdiText in the custom activity are reflected into the original EditText

Now, I know how to do this, but the point of this is to be able to create something reusable and easy to apply to all the activities/fragments inside the Settings app.
If I had to do it only for one activity I would just use startActivityForResult() when an EditText is pressed or focused.

Any idea how to implement something more generic and reusable?

Thanks